# Remove /r/n in a Python 3 Web Server

Tags: python, cgitb

I'm working on a game in Python (for fun).  However, I've come into a few issues where the game looks for a page to return the string "1", but the actual return is "1\r\n".  This fouls my response checking.  Is there any way to handle both strings?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8")
print()

print(1)
```

Comment: try `.strip()` on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options, depending upon the range of inputs you expect.

The first, as @ryugie already gave you, is to **strip** whitespace off the string:

```
text = text.strip()
```

If you have single-character input, you can simply grab the first character:

```
text = text[0]
```

If you want to go directly to the integer value, you can directly convert the string; whitespace is ignored:

```
in_value = int(text)
```

Do those fit your needs?

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't realise it was that simple! Though it'd be something more  to do with the web server, thanks again :)